# selectedindexchanged event of dropdownlist in asp.net not fired after reseting its selected value by Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two dropdownlist. When I change 1st dropdown then the 2nd one is reseted to selected index 0 by the following jQuery code.

```
    $("select[id*='ddlWayType']").bind("change", function () {
        $("select[id*='ddlVehicle']").val("Select");
    });
```

My seconddropdown has AutoPostBack="true" and SelectedIndexChange event. 
My problem is after reseting, when i select item from 2nd dropdown then a request is gone normally to server but selectedindexchange event of the 2nd dropdown  is  not get fired. Which is fired normally when we not reset selected index of 2nd DropDown by jquery.

Comment: First of all it should be on `change` event rather than `click` event of select box.

Comment: @wizkid ya , i do the same ,but it is not the cause of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the server side state with client side state. The changes made at the client side will not make change in the view state/control state. So, if you select anything other than default selected value for `ddlVehicle` dropdown, it will call the `ddlVehicle_SelectedIndexChanged` registered at server side. I have verified the same at my end as well.

---

You can achieve this by adding a web method/ajax and perform the same operation on client side change as well.

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $("select[id*='ddlWayType']").bind("change", function () {
                $("select[id*='ddlVehicle']").val("Select");
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWayType" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select1" Value="Select1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select2" Value="Select2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVehicle" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlVehicle_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select1" Value="Select1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select2" Value="Select2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It means we are not able to call, selectedIndexchange twice one after the another for the same value of the drop down.

Comment: @VishwajeetSinghChouhan Yes, it will be only called once you change the selected value, not for the same value.

Comment: @VishwajeetSinghChouhan Does this answer your question??